# WooCommerce: Finding the products in database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm creating a website using WooCommerce and I want to restrict the available products to users depending on the postcode that they enter in the search form on my home page.

To be able to achieve that I'll have to specify the conditions of each product within the database in phpMyAdmin, but I can't seem to find it.

Does anybody know where the woocommerce database for products and/or categories are within phpmyAdmin?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

**Update 2020**

Products are located mainly in the following tables:

- `wp_posts` table with `post_type` like **`product`** (or **`product_variation`**),
- `wp_postmeta` table with `post_id` as relational index (the product ID).
- `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` table with `product_id` as relational index (the post ID) | Allow fast queries on specific product data (since WooCommerce 3.7)
- `wp_wc_order_product_lookup`table with `product_id` as relational index (the post ID) | Allow fast queries to retrieve products on orders (since WooCommerce 3.7)

Product types, categories, subcategories, tags, attributes and all other custom taxonomies are located in the following tables:

- `wp_terms`
- `wp_termmeta`
- `wp_term_taxonomy`
- `wp_term_relationships` - column `object_id` as relational index *(the product ID)*
- `wp_woocommerce_termmeta`
- `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` *(for product attributes only)*
- `wp_wc_category_lookup` *(for product categories hierarchy only since WooCommerce 3.7)*

---

**Product types** are handled by custom taxonomy `product_type` with the following default terms:

- `simple`
- `grouped`
- `variable`
- `external`

*Some other product types for Subscriptions and Bookings plugins:*

- *`subscription`*
- *`variable-subscription`*
- *`booking`*

---

Since Woocommerce 3+ a new custom taxonomy named **`product_visibility`** handle:

- The product visibility with the terms `exclude-from-search` and `exclude-from-catalog`
- The feature products with the term `featured`
- The stock status with the term `outofstock`
- The rating system with terms from `rated-1` to `rated-5`

Particular feature: Each **product attribute** is a custom taxonomy…

---

References:

- Normal tables: [Wordpress database description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)
- Specific tables: [Woocommerce database description](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description)

Comment: I cannot find where Woocomerce store the relation Product -> Vendors.
I'm trying to assing from the frontend a vendor to a product.

Comment: @Pickeroll This is because some vendor plugins have their own custom tables…

Comment: cannot find the `product_type` taxonomy, what table are you looking at? I dont have a `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` of course checkign with right prefix in my case.

Comment: @S.Redrum It's on wp_term_taxonomy table

Comment: @ChrisCox in wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy (and wp_term_relationships)…

Answer (score 20):

The following tables are store WooCommerce products database :

- **wp_posts** -

  The core of the WordPress data is the posts. It is stored a `post_type` like product or `variable_product`.
- **wp_postmeta**-

  Each post features information called the meta data and it is stored in the wp_postmeta. Some plugins may add their own information to this table like WooCommerce plugin store `product_id` of product in wp_postmeta table.

Product categories, subcategories stored in this table :

- wp_terms
- wp_termmeta
- wp_term_taxonomy
- wp_term_relationships
- wp_woocommerce_termmeta

following **Query** Return a list of **product categories**

```
SELECT wp_terms.* 
    FROM wp_terms 
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
    WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat';
```

> for more reference -
>
> - [Database Description](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description)
> - [Fetch the Products of Woocommerce from it’s Table in Database](http://www.wptutorialsacademy.com/fetch-products-woocommerce-table-database/)

Answer (score 1):

Bulk add new categories to Woo:

Insert category id, name, url key

```
INSERT INTO wp_terms 
VALUES
  (57, 'Apples', 'fruit-apples', '0'),
  (58, 'Bananas', 'fruit-bananas', '0');
```

Set the term values as catergories

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy 
VALUES
  (57, 57, 'product_cat', '', 17, 0),
  (58, 58, 'product_cat', '', 17, 0)
```

17 - is parent category, if there is one

**key here is to make sure the wp_term_taxonomy table term_taxonomy_id, term_id are equal to wp_term table's  term_id**

After doing the steps above go to wordpress admin and save any existing category. This will update the DB to include your bulk added categories

Answer (score 1):

get product category IDs by providing product_id (wp_posts ID column):

```
SELECT
    term_taxonomy_id
FROM
    wp_term_relationships
WHERE
    object_id = PRODUCT_ID_HERE
    AND
    term_taxonomy_id IN
        (
            SELECT
                term_taxonomy_id
            FROM
                wp_term_taxonomy
            WHERE
                taxonomy LIKE 'product_cat'
        )
```

get category data (name, slug) and category hierarchical structure:

```
SELECT
    wp_terms.term_id,
    wp_terms.name,
    wp_terms.slug,
    wp_term_taxonomy.parent
FROM
    wp_terms
LEFT JOIN
    wp_term_taxonomy
    ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE
    wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy LIKE 'product_cat'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [WordPress custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to store eligible postcodes for each product. [add_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) and [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) are what you're looking for. It's not recommended to alter the default WordPress table structure. All postmetas are inserted in `wp_postmeta` table. You can find the corresponding products within `wp_posts` table.