# WordPress database with WooCommerce plugin is not showing all the data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have build a website using wordpress with woocommerce plugin where obvioudly database is created by woocomerce plugin and I did not bother to look at it how it happened. I can see all images and products information  everything on my website.

I got stuck now, as I need to update that database using php script with a csv file. I dont have any other option as this is the requirement.

When i looked at the database structure using sqlyog, I can see tables like wp_post, wp_postmeta as I understood through google that these are two core tables get updated by woocommerce.

I have a used goods page on my website, and wp_post just has product type = page, now I cant find anything for that page like my products ids, attributes, images, everything together there.

I have checked for other essential tables like 
wp_terms
wp_termmeta
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_term_relationships
wp_woocommerce_termmeta
by this question here
[WooCommerce: Finding the products in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965352/woocommerce-finding-the-products-in-database)

but I cant find all this information.

Now my question is is wordpress along with woocommerce do not save all the information in database?

or the structure is more than then above mentioned tables.

I have checked all other tables in my database, I cant see all information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **All WC data is mostly stored in Database.** Sessions as cart for non logged users are also using cookies…

There is also special tables for woocommerce which are:

```
wp_woocommerce_api_keys
wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies -
wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
wp_woocommerce_log
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
wp_woocommerce_order_items
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens
wp_woocommerce_sessions
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods
wp_woocommerce_tax_rates
wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations
wp_woocommerce_termmeta
```

**For example the Order *(line)* items data are located in that 2 tables:**

```
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
wp_woocommerce_order_items
```

Comment: Thak you Loic :-) I understood it much better now.