# WooCommerce SQL query to get product by tag, category, price and size/color variation attributes

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up a chat-bot on my Wordpress / Woocommerce website. I want the chat-bot to recommend the user products by asking the user some basic questions like "What clothing color are you looking for?" ,"What price range","What size", "What type of clothing (Jeans, Shirts, etc), and also by Category (Men or Women).

I already made a webhook for my dialog flow chat-bot to connect to my Wordpress database and it works fine. 
But then I took a look into the database, and I don't know if it's just me or I have some kind of dyslexia, but I can't figure out how the database is structured...

What I'm trying to get is a table with the product details (inclusive product link) and image etc by asking the user questions about the Size, Color,price range , category and tags. But it looks like everything is in another table.

Some help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Look at [*"WooCommerce: Finding the products in database"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965352/woocommerce-finding-the-products-in-database/36973435#36973435) answer thread and the provided links to database structure in WordPress and WooCommerce. This should help you a bit.

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec I checked your link and it was helpful, I edited my answer could you check it please :) ?