# Woocommerce : How to temporary disabled stock management in php \

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom product with some specific requirement for users to select, but one of the option does not need stock calculation.

Anyone can help or have any clue or ideas for this issued? many thanks for the help sincerely!

Comment: This is just about settings… On the desired product variation (option), from your variable product, you can disable stock management (checkbox), and on the other product variations (options)  check that stock management is enabled. Now the stock management on the parent variable product should be disabled.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but do you have any ideas which db is related to update the stock details

Comment: For stock status it's related to Wordpress terms tables, for other stock data it's related to wp_postmeta table. see [WooCommerce: Finding the products in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965352/woocommerce-finding-the-products-in-database/36973435#36973435)