# Hide specific products on woocommerce when ACF true/false is true in a product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom field true/false, and I want when true is selected in a product not to be displayed in the eshop.
I want to insert the code inside the functions.php

example

```
if ( in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) || !is_user_logged_in()  ) {

$postid = get_the_ID();
$prd_only_for_Customers = get_field('prd_clients', $postid); // The ACF true/false field }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Can you include more details on your variables and more of the function, so that someone could recreate this on a test environment? [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Howard said your question is incomplete but you can use the following method to set product hidden.

You can use `pre_get_posts` hook in your functions.php. Since Woocommerce 3 the products visibility is now handled by the 'product_visibility' custom taxonomy for the terms 'exclude-from-catalog' and 'exclude-from-search'… See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965352/woocommerce-finding-the-products-in-database/36973435#36973435) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482690/database-changes-for-products-in-woocommerce-3/48487242#48487242) too.

So you should use instead the [`WC_Product` CRUD setter methods `set_catalog_visibility()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_set_catalog_visibility) this way:

```
function get_post_ids_by_meta_key_and_value($key, $value) {
    global $wpdb;

    $meta = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM `".$wpdb->postmeta."` WHERE meta_key='".$wpdb->escape($key)."' AND meta_value='".$wpdb->escape($value)."'");

    $post_ids = [];
    foreach( $meta as $m ) {
        $post_ids[] = $m->post_id;
    }

    return $post_ids;
}


add_action('pre_get_posts', function( $query ){
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $product_ids = get_post_ids_by_meta_key_and_value('prd_clients', 1);
        foreach($product_ids as $id){
            // Get an instance of the product
            $product = wc_get_product($id);
            // Change the product visibility
            $product->set_catalog_visibility('hidden');
            // Save and sync the product visibility
            $product->save();
        }
    }
});
```

*This code isn't tested, let me know if it worked or you faced any problem.*

Comment: I think the code you've written is what I'm looking for. 
But the problem is that the product that has prd_clients set as true still appears in the directory.
Also i checked to find why its not hiding it and i found that inside the if statement when i echo $prd_only_for_Customers; i dont get back anything

Comment: Outside of the second if statement when i make 

`echo '<pre>';
var_dump($postid);
var_dump($prd_only_for_Customers);
echo '</pre>'; `

i get :

`bool(false)
NULL`

Comment: The issues was in `$postid`. I updated the code please check.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code if anyone needs something like this

```
// Specific products show only for Customer and administrator role
add_action('pre_get_posts', function( $query ){
    
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce()) {
        if (!check_user_role(array('customer','administrator')) || !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $product_ids = get_post_ids_by_meta_key_and_value('prd_clients', 1);
            foreach($product_ids as $id){
                // Get an instance of the product
                $product = wc_get_product($id);
                // Change the product visibility
                $product->set_catalog_visibility('hidden');
                // Save and sync the product visibility
                $product->save();
            }
        }
        else{
            $product_ids = get_post_ids_by_meta_key_and_value('prd_clients', 1);
            foreach($product_ids as $id){
                // Get an instance of the product
                $product = wc_get_product($id);
                // Change the product visibility
                $product->set_catalog_visibility('visible');
                // Save and sync the product visibility
                $product->save();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
});
```